# How can I use std::maps with user-defined types as key?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, containers, stdmap

I'm wondering why I can't use STL maps with user-defined classes. When I compile the code below, I get the following cryptic error message. What does it mean? Also, why is it only happening with user-defined types? (Primitive types are okay when they are used as key.)

> C:\MinGW\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5........\include\c++\3.4.5\bits\stl_function.h||In
>   member function `bool
>   std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&,
>   const _Tp&) const [with _Tp =
>   Class1]':|
>
> C:\MinGW\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5........\include\c++\3.4.5\bits\stl_map.h|338|instantiated
>   from `_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp,
>   _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) [with _Key = Class1, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less, _Alloc = std::allocator >]'|
>
> C:\Users\Admin\Documents\dev\sandbox\sandbox\sandbox.cpp|24|instantiated
>   from here|
>
> C:\MinGW\bin..\lib\gcc\mingw32\3.4.5........\include\c++\3.4.5\bits\stl_function.h|227|error: no match for 'operator<' in '__x <
>   __y'| ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Class1
{
public:
    Class1(int id);

private:
    int id;
};

Class1::Class1(int id): id(id)
{}

int main()
{
    Class1 c1(1);

    map< Class1 , int> c2int;
    c2int[c1] = 12;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ unordered\_map using a custom class type as the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016175/c-unordered-map-using-a-custom-class-type-as-the-key)

Answer (score 180):

You don't *have* to define `operator<` for your class, actually. You can also make a comparator function object class for it, and use that to specialize `std::map`. To extend your example:

```
struct Class1Compare
{
   bool operator() (const Class1& lhs, const Class1& rhs) const
   {
       return lhs.id < rhs.id;
   }
};

std::map<Class1, int, Class1Compare> c2int;
```

It just so happens that the default for the third template parameter of `std::map` is [`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less), which will delegate to `operator<` defined for your class (and fail if there is none). But sometimes you want objects to be usable as map keys, but you do not actually have any *meaningful* comparison semantics, and so you don't want to confuse people by providing `operator<` on your class just for that. If that's the case, you can use the above trick.

Yet another way to achieve the same is to specialize `std::less`:

```
namespace std
{
    template<> struct less<Class1>
    {
       bool operator() (const Class1& lhs, const Class1& rhs) const
       {
           return lhs.id < rhs.id;
       }
    };
}
```

The advantage of this is that it will be picked by `std::map` "by default", and yet you do not expose `operator<` to client code otherwise.

Comment: I would suggest adding a const keyword to the two functions.

Comment: maybe it is worthwhile to `friend` with the struct less otherwise I see it as a compromised encapsulation.

Comment: The templated struct should be ended with a semicolon, otherwise you get compilation errors. Unfortunately I could not fix this with an edit due to the low amount of changed characters

Comment: But why are you putting struct less info std?

Comment: It's already in `std`. This is just a specialization of that.

Answer (score 35):

By default [`std::map`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) (and [`std::set`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/)) use [`operator<`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/less/) to determine sorting. Therefore, you need to define `operator<` on your class.

Two objects are deemed [equivalent](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) `if !(a < b) && !(b < a)`.

If, for some reason, you'd like to use a different comparator, the third template argument of the `map` can be changed, to [`std::greater`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/functional/greater/), for example.

Comment: As a matter of fact, you can change the comparator to most any two-argument function.

Answer (score 22):

You need to define `operator <` for the Class1.

Map needs to compare the values using operator < and hence you need to provide the same when user defined class are used as key.

```
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1(int id);

    bool operator <(const Class1& rhs) const
    {
        return id < rhs.id;
    }
private:
    int id;
};
```

Comment: It doesn't need operator< ; it merely defaults to it.  See GMan's or Pavel's answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
class key
{
    int m_value;
public:
    bool operator<(const key& src)const
    {
        return (this->m_value < src.m_value);
    }

};
int main()
{
    key key1;
    key key2;
    map<key,int> mymap;
    mymap.insert(pair<key,int>(key1,100));
    mymap.insert(pair<key,int>(key2,200));
    map<key,int>::iterator iter=mymap.begin();
    for(;iter!=mymap.end();++iter)
    {
        cout<<iter->second<<endl;
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some explanations to your answer.

Answer (score 6):

## Your example [works in C++20](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9dEdjh7G4) if you just add

```
auto operator<=>(Class1 const &) const = default;
```

to your class.

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to expand a little bit on *Pavel Minaev's* [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1102720/2675154), which you should read before reading my answer. Both solutions presented by Pavel won't compile if the member to be compared (such as `id` in the question's code) is private. In this case, VS2013 throws the following error for me:

> error C2248: 'Class1::id' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Class1'

As mentioned by *SkyWalker* in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102392/stdmaps-with-user-defined-types-as-key?rq=1#comment17162733_1102720) on *Pavel's* answer, using a `friend` declaration helps. If you wonder about the correct syntax, here it is:

```
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1(int id) : id(id) {}

private:
    int id;
    friend struct Class1Compare;      // Use this for Pavel's first solution.
    friend struct std::less<Class1>;  // Use this for Pavel's second solution.
};
```

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/VCfU0m)

However, if you have an access function for your private member, for example `getId()` for `id`, as follows:

```
class Class1
{
public:
    Class1(int id) : id(id) {}
    int getId() const { return id; }

private:
    int id;
};
```

then you can use it instead of a `friend` declaration (i.e. you compare `lhs.getId() < rhs.getId()`).
Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), you can also use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) for *Pavel's* first solution instead of defining a comparator function object class.
Putting everything together, the code could be written as follows:

```
auto comp = [](const Class1& lhs, const Class1& rhs){ return lhs.getId() < rhs.getId(); };
std::map<Class1, int, decltype(comp)> c2int(comp);
```

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/pp2Bw6)

Comment: Can you let me know why the member variable won't be accessible because operator< overloading happens inside the same class right? so within class even private member variable should be accessible .

Comment: @m_alpha: Pavel's and my solutions don't define operator< for Class1. The comparators are defined outside Class1. Therefore, they can't access private members of Class1.

Answer (score 3):

Keys must be comparable, but you haven't defined a suitable `operator<` for your custom class.

Answer (score 1):

**The right solution is to Specialize `std::less` for your class/Struct.**

• Basically maps in cpp are implemented as Binary Search Trees.

1. BSTs compare elements of nodes to determine the organization of the tree.
2. Nodes who's element compares less than that of the parent node are placed on the left of the parent and nodes whose elements compare greater than the parent nodes element are placed on the right.
   i.e.

> For each node, node.left.key < node.key < node.right.key

Every node in the BST contains Elements and in case of maps its KEY and a value, And keys are supposed to be ordered.
More About Map implementation :  [The Map data Type](http://www.panix.com/~elflord/cpp/stdlib/map.html).

In case of cpp maps , keys are the elements of the nodes and values does not take part in the organization of the tree its just a supplementary data .

So It means keys should be compatible with `std::less` or `operator<` so that they can be organized. Please check [map parameters](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/#parameters).

Else if you are using user defined data type as keys then need to give meaning full comparison semantics for that data type.

**Solution** : Specialize `std::less`:

The third parameter in map template is optional and it is `std::less` which will delegate to `operator<` ,

So create a new   `std::less` for your user defined data type. Now this new `std::less` will be picked by `std::map` by default.

```
namespace std
{
    template<> struct  less<MyClass>
    {
        bool operator() (const MyClass& lhs, const MyClass& rhs) const
        {
            return lhs.anyMemen < rhs.age;
        }
    };

}
```

Note: You need to create specialized `std::less` for every user defined data type(if you want to use that data type as key for cpp maps).

***Bad Solution:***
Overloading `operator<` for your user defined data type.
This solution will also work but its very bad as operator `<` will be overloaded universally for your data type/class. which is undesirable in client scenarios.

Please check answer [Pavel Minaev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102392/stdmaps-with-user-defined-types-as-key/51997988#answer-1102720)

Comment: What do you mean by "overloaded universally"?

Comment: Overloading `operator <` is more meaningful and useful while the instances are naturally comparable. eg. `struct Level { int level1; int level2; };`