# c++ correct way to push class members to vector

Tags: c++, class, oop, vector

I have a simple class that is the concatenation of 2 objects from other libraries:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   Thing1 thing1;
   Thing2 thing2;  
};
```

What I want is to be able to ensure that when I plow through a list of thing1s and I want to know about something in the associated thing2, I can get the right answer. So I make a vector out MyClass:

```
std::vector<MyClass> myClasses;
```

So far so good. Now I want to populate this vector's `thing1` members from  a vector of `thing1`s. All I could come up with is:

```
MyClass someStuff;
for(unsigned i=0; i<thing1Vec.size(); i++) {
    someStuff.thing1 = thing1Vec[i];
    myClasses.push_back(someStuff);
}
```

This works, but it seems inelegant and non-C++ to me.

I thought about inheriting from Thing1 and Thing2, but I have to pass instances to other methods later on. I don't know how else to set up the class that allows for this.

I'm a bit of a C++ newb, so I could be thinking about this problem all wrong. If anyone has better code fo this kind of thing, I'd love to see it.

I think this is exactly why people use Python.

Comment: It's not clear how you populate `thing2`.  Is that in another vector the same size as `thing2Vec`?

Comment: who cares about that? the point is that I can't just have a vector of thing1s

Comment: "I think this is exactly why people use Python.", use Python.

Comment: Excuse me, but it may very much matter, because you have asked for a tidy answer.  If the two are parallel vectors, there _is_ a very nice solution.  If the relationship is different, then _other_ solutions are more appropriate.  If you are asked for clarification on an unclear part of your question by people who have a lot of C++ experience, it is a little rude to say "who cares".

Comment: I apologize -- I didn't mean to be rude, just being direct. I suppose you are right and that I was thinking about this problem incorrectly. But I would still like to know if there is a more idiomatic way to shove members of a class into the objects in a vector of that class than what I described in the question.

Comment: It would help greatly if you would explain what the actual relationship of `thing2` is.  Are they in a vector?  Or is there only one?

Comment: thing2 would also be in a vector, but the sizes might not actually match. I think pm100 gave me the answer I am looking for. However, I'm not sure the objects will actually 'map nice as he says..

Comment: How do you determine which element of `thing2Vec` will be associated with an element of `thing1Vec`?

Comment: If `thing1vec` and `thing2vec` are of different sizes and you still want to associated `thing1` to `thing2`, then map the first `n` elements in the both vectors (n is the size of the smaller vector) and leave out the rest. Or maybe you have a way to determine the which elements go in the mapping.

Comment: Well, I have a potential answer for you but it depends on how you describe the true relationship between elements in your two vectors.

Comment: I ended up structuring the whole method differently. I thought this would be an interesting question (I was curious as to the answer) but I guess not. I will continue to work with vectors in my Luddite fashion. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3):

it sounds like you want to make a relationship between a thing1 and a thing2. putting them in the same class is not necessarily the right way to do it

how about

```
std::map<Thing1, Thing2> thingrel;
// create map
thingrel[t1_1] = t2_1;
.....
// lookup later
Thing2 t2_x= thingrel[t1_x];
```

Its hard to say if this is right - since your code is so abstract

you will need to make sure Thing1 is 'map nice' . see [std::maps with user-defined types as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102392/stdmaps-with-user-defined-types-as-key)

Comment: Sorry about that. I think what you suggest is exactly what I am looking for, though! Thanks.