# Invalid operands to binary expression ('const' and 'const' )

Tags: c++

I am a C++ noob,  so please don’t mind if you find this question silly

I am declaring map in C++ a below:

```
std::map<CartesianLocation, std::list<RadioSignal<RadioDevice>>> radioMap;
```

Full code:

Don't know but using below code, I could able to solve my issue

```cpp
class RadioMap:public std::iterator_traits<CartesianLocation>, public Cloneable<RadioMap> {
private:
    std::map<const CartesianLocation*, const std::list<RadioSignal<RadioDevice>>*> radioMap;
    std::vector<RadioDevice> radioDevices;

public:
    void add(const CartesianLocation *location, const std::list<RadioSignal<RadioDevice>> *observedSignals){
        radioMap[location] = observedSignals;
}
```

On this line `radioMap[location] = observedSignals;` I am ended with this error

> “Invalid operands to binary expression ('const CartesianLocation' and
>   'const CartesianLocation’)” on struct _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY less :
>   binary_function<_Tp, _Tp, bool> {
>       _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11 _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY 
>       bool operator()(const _Tp& __x, const _Tp& __y) const
>           {return __x < __y;} };

Any idea where I may be wrong?

Comment: I think because you have user defined types specifically `CatersianLocation` and whatever `RadioSignal` and `RadioDevice` is they need to define the less than operator `<` for the comparator in the `map` to order the elements correctly, see related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102392/stdmaps-with-user-defined-types-as-key or you can define a comparator functor as suggested in the linked question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are not providing a comparator for `std::map`, and so it uses `std::less`. But `std::less` doesn't have an overload for `CartesianLocation` (and `CartesianLocation` doesn't have an `operator<`), so you get an error.

You can add an `operator<`:

```
struct CartesianLocation
{
    //Other stuff
    bool operator<(const CartesianLocation& loc2) const
    {
        //Return true if this is less than loc2
    }
};
```

Another way is to define a custom comparator, for example:

```
struct comp
{
    bool operator()(const CartesianLocation& loc1, const CartesianLocation& loc2) const
    {
        //Compare the 2 locations, return true if loc1 is less than loc2
    }
};
```

Then you can pass it to `std::map`:

```
std::map<CartesianLocation, std::list<RadioSignal<RadioDevice>>, comp> radioMap;
```

Comment: For completness, two other options would be to specialize `less` for `CartesianLocation` or defined `operator<` for it.

Comment: @SergeyA can you really specialize `less`?? I thought you can't do that for `std` functions..

Comment: Yes, you can. There is a special exception - while you can't define new names inside `std`, you can provide specializations. Also, your member `operator<` definition is incorrect.

Comment: @SergeyA oh, didn't know that. But it doesn't apply to templates, right?

Comment: @SergeyA - you can specialize templates in `std` **for user-defined types**.

Comment: The two-argument `operator<` needs to be a free function. If it's a member it should take one argument and be `const`.

Comment: @PeteBecker, of course, and this is something I forgot to mention in my comment.

Comment: Don't know but using below code, I could able to solve my issue: