# Use existing object in vector or create new if not exists in C++

Tags: c++, pointers

Let's assume that I have a class named Store which contains products. Functions are inlined for simplicity.

```
class Store
{
public:
    Store(string name)
        : _name(name)
    {}

    string getName() const
    { return _name; };

    const std::vector<string> getProducts()
    { return _products; };

    void addProduct(const string& product)
    { _products.push_back(product); }

private:
    const string _name;
    std::vector<string> _products;
};
```

Then I have a two dimensional string array which contains store-product -pairs. Same store can be multiple times in array.

```
string storeListing[4][2] = {{"Lidl", "Meat"},
                             {"Walmart", "Milk"},
                             {"Lidl", "Milk"},
                             {"Walmart", "Biscuits"}};
```

Now I want to iterate through array, create Store-object for each store in array and add products of it to object. So I need to use existing Store-object or create a new if there is no any with correct name yet. What is a way to implement this? Currently I'm trying to use pointer and set it to relevant object, but I'm getting sometimes segmentation faults and sometimes other nasty problems when I modify code slightly. I guess I'm calling some undefined behavior here.

```
std::vector<Store> stores;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    string storeName = storeListing[i][0];
    string productName = storeListing[i][1];

    Store* storePtr = nullptr;
    for (Store& store : stores) {
        if (store.getName() == storeName) {
            storePtr = &store;
        }
    }

    if (storePtr == nullptr) {
        Store newStore(storeName);
        stores.push_back(newStore);
        storePtr = &newStore;
    }

    storePtr->addProduct(productName);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map)) would be more useful here?

Comment: [OT]: getProducts() should return reference (and be const).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, because you insert "Store" copies into your vector:

```
if (storePtr == nullptr) {
    Store newStore(storeName);   //create Store on stack
    stores.push_back(newStore);  //Make a COPY that is inserted into the vec
    storePtr = &newStore;       // And this is where it all goes wrong.
}
```

newStore goes out of scope at the end of the if and StorePtr is lost.

Try it with:

```
storePtr = stores.back();
```

Or make your vector a `std::vector<Store*>`.

And then:

```
if (storePtr == nullptr) {
Store * newStore = new Store(storeName);   //create Store on stack
stores.push_back(newStore);  //Make a COPY that is inserted into the vec
storePtr = newStore;       // And this is where it all goes wrong.
}
```

And of course, as the comments suggest, a std::map would be better suited here.

In short, std::map stores key-value pairs. The key would most likely be your store name, and the value the product.

Quick example:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string> myMap;
myMap["Lidl"] = "Milk";
myMap["Billa"] = "Butter";
//check if store is in map:
if(myMap.find("Billa") != myMap.end())
  ....
```

Note, you can of course use your `Store` object as value. To use it as key, you have to take care of a few things:

[std::maps with user-defined types as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102392/stdmaps-with-user-defined-types-as-key)

For your specific example i would suggest you use a `std::string` as key, and a vector of `Products` as value.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::unordered_set<Store>`, where the hash type is the string name of the store. Using a `map`-like type would lead to duplicated storage of the store name (one time as a key to the map and one time inside the `Store` object itself).

```
template <>
struct std::hash<Store> {
    using Store = argument_type;
    using result_type = std::size_t;
    result_type operator()(const argument_type& s) const noexcept {
       return result_type{ std::hash<std::string>{}(s._name) }();
    }
};

std::unordered_set<Store> stores;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
   string storeName = storeListing[i][0];
   string productName = storeListing[i][1];

   auto iter = stores.find(storeName);
   if(iter == stores.end()) iter = stores.emplace(storeName);
   iter->addProduct(productName);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems in your approach.

Problem 1:

Store has a const data member. This will make it impossible to reorder the vector of stores. That needs to be corrected.

Problem 2:

You need to point at the right Store after insertion. Here's one approach:

```
// decompose the problem:
// first step - get a pointer (iterator) to a mutable store *in the vector*
auto locate_or_new(std::vector<Store>& stores, std::string const& storeName)
-> std::vector<Store>::iterator
{
    auto iter = std::find_if(begin(stores), end(stores),
                             [&](Store& store)
                             {
                                 return store.getName() == storeName;
                             });
    if (iter == end(stores))
    {
        iter = stores.emplace(end(stores), storeName);
    }
    return iter;
}

//
// 2 - insert the product in terms of the above function.    
auto addProduct(std::vector<Store>& stores, std::string const& storeName, std::string const& productName)
-> std::vector<Store>::iterator
{
    auto istore = locate_or_new(stores, storeName);
    istore->addProduct(productName);
    return istore;
}
```

Note:

Since inserting objects into a vector can cause iterator invalidation, you will need to be careful to not hold references to objects inside the vector across sections of code that could create new stores.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the problem with const data member and vector? Do you mean that I should never use const data members if I plan to store objects of class in vector?

Comment: @PaulusLimma yes - because when you extend the vector it is possible that objects will need to be moved. They can't be moved if they are immutable.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (storePtr == nullptr) {
        Store newStore(storeName);
        stores.push_back(newStore);
        storePtr = &newStore;
    }
```

Once the `if` ends `newStore` is gone and you are left with dangling pointer `storePtr`.
You could use an `std::set<Store *>` here

```
std::set<Store *> myset;
Store *c = new Store("store3");
std::set<Store *>::iterator iter = myset.find(c);
if(iter!=myset.end())
{
   (*iter)->addProduct("Product1");
}
else
{
   c->addProduct("Product1");
   myset.insert(c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution using vectors and iterators. Dont forget to include the "algorithm" header!

```
std::vector<Store> stores;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    string storeName = storeListing[i][0];
    string productName = storeListing[i][1];

    auto storeIter = std::find_if(stores.begin(), stores.end(), [storeName](Store store) -> bool {
        return store.getName() == storeName;
    }); //Find the store in the vector

    if (storeIter == stores.end()) //If the store doesn't exists
    {
        stores.push_back(Store(storeName)); //Add the store to the vector
        storeIter = prev(stores.end()); //Get the last element from the vector
    }
    Store* storePtr = &(*storeIter); //You can convert the iterator into a pointer if you really need it
    storeIter->addProduct(productName);
    //storePtr->addProduct(productName);
}
```