# Printing a map of object, which has another object as Key

Tags: c++, class, c++11, operator-overloading, stdmap

I am trying to print the contents of my `map <Object, int>`. Here is the code in question:

```
void Inventory::print_initial_inventory()
{
    for(auto p : inventory) {
        std::cout << p.first << " : " << p.second << std::endl;
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outstream, Inventory& inv) 
{
    outstream << inv.first << "\nNumber of parts: " << inv.second << std::endl;
    return outstream;
}
```

I know the problem is at `p.first`?  because `std::cout` doesn't know **how to print an object**, so I tried to overload the `operator<<` , but I'm not sure how to do it. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

**EDIT** Here's how I've tried the problem again. I was suggested to pass the **key** type to the `operator<<` overload. Here is my code now:

```
void Inventory::print_initial_inventory()
{
    for(auto x : inventory) {
        std::cout << x.first << " : " << x.second << std::endl;
    }
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outstream, Auto_Part& inv)
{
    outstream << "Type: " << inv.type << "\nName: " << inv.name << "\nPart Number: " << inv.part_number << "\nPrice: $" << inv.price << std::endl;
    return outstream;
}
```

I'm still getting an **invalid binary expression error** pointing to `x.first`.

Comment: For some reason, my question is not displaying properly. The map key is an object type, and the map value is an int type.

Comment: You need an `operator<<()` for the type the maps key is of.

Comment: Do I still include std::ostream& as a parameter?

Comment: `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &os, WhateverYourType const &wyt);`

Comment: I think that's what I did in this line: 

    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& outstream, Inventory& inv)

No? Inv is a pointer to an Inventory object.

Comment: "You need an operator<<() **for the type the maps key is of**"

Comment: To answer this properly, you should expose more code. What is `Inventory`? Form your exposed code, it seems to have a member variable `Inventory::inventory` which seems to be a container. This doesn't answer why it should have a `first` and `second`. Please, make a [mcve] and [edit] it into your question if you want a sufficient answer.

Comment: My key type is a class called Auto_Part. I'm going to edit the original post to show you how I've changed it. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I really wonder why this question got two upvotes where other questions with proper problem description and MCVE got down-votes simply because they presented beginner problems.

Comment: Please, consider the **Complete** in [mcve]. Complete means, I can copy/paste your code to an online compiler and try by myself.

Comment: Sorry, for not being complete. I tried to be minimal. I am editing the post now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the problem is at `p.first`? because `std::cout` doesn't know
>   how to print an `object`, so I tried to overload the `<< operator`,
>   but I'm not sure how to do it.

The basics of operator overloading can be found in this post: [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)
 I strongly recommend to read this before you step further

In your case I found two basic issues:

1. You have not mentioned your `Key` class a lot. Especially, how would you insert the element to the `std::map`(member of `Inventory` class), if you do not provide `operator<`? Since `Key` class is a user-defined you need to give one. You can read more about it in this SO post:[std::maps with user-defined types as key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102392/stdmaps-with-user-defined-types-as-key)
2. Second and main issue of your code is, not providing a [`operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) for your `Key` type. That can be done as follows:

For instance, let's say `class Key`

```
class Key
{
    int member;
public:
    Key(const int a): member(a){}
    // provide operator< for your Key type
    bool operator<(const Key& other)const { return this->member < other.member; }
   // provide operator<< for Key class like follows
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Key& key);
};
// implement outside the class
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Key& key)
{
    // simply for this case
    return out << key.member;
}
```

and now you can provide `operator<<` for `Inventory` class in a similar manner.

<kbd>**[SEE LIVE EXAMPLE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hdWCFwzIMNH3aKsV)**</kbd>

```
// now in Inventory class
class Inventory
{
   std::map<Key, int> inventory;
public:
    Inventory(const std::map<Key, int>& m): inventory(std::move(m)) {}
    // declared as friend, so that you can access the private member(map)
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Inventory& inv);
};
// implement outside the class
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Inventory& inv)
{
    for(const auto& entry: inv.inventory )
        out << entry.first << " Number of parts: " << entry.second << std::endl;
    return out;
}
// in the main
int main()
{
    Key key1{1};
    Key key2{2};
    std::map<Key, int> tempInvObj{{key1, 11}, {key2, 12}};
    Inventory obj{tempInvObj};
    std::cout << obj;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1 Number of parts: 11
2 Number of parts: 12
```

Comment: I tried this, and this is the error I'm getting: error: invalid range expression of type 'Inventory'; no viable 'begin' function available
    for(auto p : inv){

Comment: The above code is right. I figured out the problem wasn't with the printing, it was with the map. Because maps are sorted, and I was trying to sort objects, I had to define how to sort objects by overloading the operator<.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` is `std::ostream` object. `std::ostream` has `operator<<` overloaded by standard for some basic types ([you can check them out here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt)). If you want to be able to use `operator<<` with your class (let's say `class MyType`), you have to overload that operator by yourself.

For built-in C++ types like `std::ostream` you perform such overloading outside class (because otherwise you'd have to modify `std::ostream`), and the syntax for that is:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& s, const MyType& arg)
{
    /* enter you implementation here */
    return s;
}
```

More info can be found [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).