# How to make user defined variables the values in maps

Tags: c++, oop, maps

Suppose I create a user defined variable in C++. How can I use that variable as a value in a map?

For example:

```
std::map<int, mytype> mappa;
```

If I could get some simple examples, so that I could understand the concept fully, that'd be great.

Comment: There's nothing special required to do so. Have you tried and run into a problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use std::maps with user-defined types as key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102392/how-can-i-use-stdmaps-with-user-defined-types-as-key)

Comment: @ArdentCoder that question is about keys, while OP asks for values, maybe a misunderstanding of OP

Comment: @idclev463035818 Yah, I saw that lol but I think there's nothing hard to use them as values imho. Maybe OP got a bunch of errors when using them as keys (like the absence of a comparison operator) :P

Comment: @ArdentCoder I am facing troubles trying to print the values. I get errors when I use cout<< , like , "Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'hotel')", hotel is the data type.

Comment: @AniketVishwakarma I can help you with that if you edit your question with an overview of your `hotel` class.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class MyClass
{
    // Upto you how your class looks like
};

int main()
{
    // A map where key = int and value = MyClass
    std::map<int, MyClass> myMap;

    // Have some objects of MyClass to demonstrate the use of myMap
    MyClass obj1, obj2, obj3;

    /* Some basic operations */

    // Example of insertion
    myMap.insert({12, obj1});
    myMap.insert({13, obj2});
    myMap.insert({22, obj3});

    // Example of deletion
    myMap.erase(22); // removes myMap[22] i.e. obj3 leaves the map

    // Example of searching
    if (myMap.find(22) != myMap.end())
    {
        // process myMap[22]
        std::cout << "myMap[22] exists";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "myMap[22] does not exist";
    }

    // ...
    return 0;
}
```

Basically, there's nothing much difficult to use a user-defined type as *values* in a map. If you meant to use them as *keys* then you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102392/how-can-i-use-stdmaps-with-user-defined-types-as-key) post.

You can also look at this [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) to learn more of its functions.

Comment: thank you so much. But I am having issues in printing the user defined data type value. if I use cout<< , it shows error such as "Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'hotel')" where hotel is the data type. I want to be able to print individual selected values from the map

Comment: @AniketVishwakarma Because you have not overloaded the stream insertion operator for your class. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/476483/10251345) will help you.